# Including files correctly , but still getting linker error

Tags: c++, linker-errors

hope you guys are doing well. I am just getting linker error in C++ , I don't know why? Everything is correct....
Check below **testing.h** file

```
#ifndef __MYClass__
#define __MYClass__
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Abc {
private:
    int a;
public:
    void input();
    void display();
};


#endif
```

and here's implementation of these functions in **Functions.cpp** file.

```
#include"testing.h"

void Abc::input() {
    cout<<"Enter any value : ";
    cin>>a;
}
void Abc::display() {
    cout<<"You Entered : "<<a;
}
```

And now, in **main.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include"testing.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    Abc obj;
    obj.input();
    obj.display();
    return 0;
}
```

All files are compiled successfully.
In **main.cpp** Linker says....
*g++ -Wall -o "main" "main.cpp" (in directory: /home/Welcome/C++ Practices/testingLinux)
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccYI9LAy.o: in function `main': main.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to` Abc::input()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `Abc::display()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Compilation failed.*
I'm using built-in linux compiler...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__MYClass__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can fix this but before that please read up on [Translation Unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c).

Coming to your problem.

When you write

```
g++ -Wall -o main main.cpp
```

The compiler will pick up `main.cpp` for compilation and expand `testing.h` that includes the **declaration** for `class ABC` and with this header file it can determine what is the size of `ABC` and be able to generate instructions reserving space for `obj` on the stack. It can't see the definition for `input()` and `display()` hence defers that task to the linker. Note that `testing.cpp` **is not** in the picture at all since the compiler doesn't know that the implementation of `ABC` is in `testing.cpp`. Now when the linker tries to resolve the symbols `input()` it fails to find the *definition* for it and throws the error

```
undefined reference to Abc::input()
```

So, to fix this you can tell explicitly upfront that it also needs to take in `testing.cpp` while compiling `main.cpp` by

```
g++ -o main main.cpp testing.cpp
```

Another way is to create a *dynamic library* out of `testing.h` and `testing.cpp`

```
g++ -shared -fPIC testing.cpp -o libtest
```

and then *link* it against `main.cpp`

```
g++ -o main  main.cpp -I. -L. libtest
```

What this does is that the compiler still can't figure out the definition of `input()` and `display()` **but** the linker can since now the library containing the **definitions** is provided to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not compiling Functions.cpp file. 
This should fix your issue:

```
g++ main.cpp Functions.cpp
```

Comment: How are you compiling the files? On Linux terminal, right? At the Linux prompt, execute this.